# Tool to create mongodb sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding, distributed-database, database-cluster, nosql

I need a tool to manage a cluster of mongodbs. With an increasing number of machines, it is hard to maintain each machine without a tool.

More details:

The database grows around 50 MB per day, so they are approximately 1.5 GB per month. The mongodb is great for this because just increase a machine in your cluster resolve the size problem. The problem is that this change requires entering the host configuration and make the changes manually. I'd like to optimize the time of the team with a tool that allows remote execution, for example, run and save scripts or similar.

Comment: can you provide more details on what exactly you need to do with each machine, also code samples on what maintenance you currently do

Comment: Here are more details:
The database grows around 50 MB per day, so they are approximately 1.5 GB per month. The mongodb is great for this because just increase a machine in your cluster resolve the size problem. The problem is that this change requires entering the host configuration and make the changes manually. I'd like to optimize the time of the team with a tool that allows remote execution, for example, run and save scripts or similar.

Comment: You need sharding for such a small amount of ops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Juju to create mongodb cluster :

https://github.com/charms/mongodb

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyZVZdGTRf8g-5E7ppGGpxrraStyi493V

http://www.jorgecastro.org/2014/03/17/introducing-juju-bundles/

Answer (score 0):

You need a provisioning tool, like [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). Or SSH wrapper like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/).

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) has a Public API that you can use for cluster deployment automation.

Here's the link to the (very well-written) [official docs](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/api/).